# Yii - map url with special character.

Tags: url, yii, hashtag, url-mapping

Im using Yii framework and want to create a page that loads users info. But I always want to have a hashtag before the userID. So the userID is dynamic and the hashtag is always there.

Target:
http://example.com/#userID

How can I resolve that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to configure `urlManager` in your main config file to add a rule to force a '#' char in your url to be resolved for your userinfo view action like this:

```
'urlManager'=>array('urlFormat'=>'path','appendParams'=>false,
    'rules'=>array('#<username:.*?>'=>'YOURACTION_ROUTE',);
```

You controller action would like this:

```
public function action_YOUR_ACTION_($username, $id)
{
   show_user_info($id);
}
```

In this way the real $id is hidden but action can catch it and process your userinfo correctly.
Or you can add some code to find user by $username without $id it's fine too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast response.
I'm also using Slugable plugin and every time I pyt the "#" in url i get: Error 400, Your request is invalid. Without the hash it works, but I need it there.